# How I can use wingdings characters on PDFLaTeX document (and not on Luatex or Xelatex)?

Tags: pdftex

I want put some wingdings symbol in line of my document.
But, I found some answer of this question concern only LuaTeX et XeLaTeX and don't work on PdfLaTeX engine.

I use this simple code for some test:

```
% ----------------------------------------------------
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,openany,twoside,francais]{book}% smfbook
% ---------------------------------------------------
% encodage caractères ; gestion des accents; rendu pdf
\usepackage{etex}%
\usepackage{ucs}%
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}%
\usepackage{lmodern}%
\usepackage[]{tipa}%
\usepackage{tipx}%
\usepackage{aeguill}
% style de mise en page général du document
% autres: Glenn,Lenny,Conny,Rejne et Bjarne, Bjornstrup
\usepackage[Sonny]{fncychap}% 
\usepackage[geometry,weather,misc,clock]{ifsym}%
% gestions des mathématiques : l'AMS + mathtools ; caractères
\usepackage{mathtools,amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts,mathrsfs}
\usepackage{bm}%
\usepackage{dcolumn}%
\usepackage[nice]{nicefrac}%
\allowdisplaybreaks
% Gestion des polices de caractères additionnels
\usepackage{pifont,eurosym,textcomp,wasysym,lmodern}
\usepackage{relsize}%
\usepackage{rotating}%

\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\wingdingsfont{Wingdings}
\newcommand\wingdings[1]{{\wingdingsfont\symbol{#1}}}
% Système international d'unité - l'indispensable 
\usepackage{siunitx}%
%
\begin{document} 

\section{Test divers}

\wingdings{40} : essais d'insertion de symbole wingdings.

Fin tests
%
\end{document}
```

And I obtain like answer, an error of compilation without creation of pdf:

```
 /usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.sty, line 43
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!
! Fatal fontspec error: "cannot-use-pdftex"
! 
! The fontspec package requires either XeTeX or LuaTeX to function.
! 
! You must change your typesetting engine to, e.g., "xelatex" or "lualatex"
! instead of plain "latex" or "pdflatex".
! 
! See the fontspec documentation for further information.
! 
! For immediate help type H <return>.
!...............................................  

l.43  }

|'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
| This is a fatal error: LaTeX will abort.
|...............................................
```

Who can help me to understand this problem?
How can use wingdings symbol on this document when engine is pdflatex only?
Thanks for you helpful.
D. Collin

Comment: There's a package for them by the author of `mathdesign`. It is  on [CTAN](http://ctan.org/pkg/winfonts) with instructions to install them on a MiKTeX system, but it's easy to adapt the installation for TeX Live.

Comment: Thank you very muh for your help. This seems working, nevertheless it is necessary to have the webdings metric (TFM) font installed!!

Comment: ??? They're in the .zip file!

Comment: I use ShareLaTeX on line, and I can't use windings symbol. So the problem is not solved at all. And on my TexLive 2106 system (on my mac Os X) also I can't use wingdings. Also I do not await any more a solution.

Answer (score 2):

Installing symbol fonts for use with pdfTeX is actually relatively straightforward if the fonts are in type1 format. If they are truetype, things are a little more complex as the fonts must be reencoded, although this isn't usually needed for symbols, and the names of the characters are naturally non-standard.

The method below depends on the version and particularities of the font(s) you have.

Because the code required exceeds the site's character limit for an answer, this answer is split into parts. This is Part 1.

I had the following (re-named) truetype fonts:

```
wingdings-book.ttf  wingdings2-book.ttf  wingdings3-book.ttf
```

The code below assumes the following character lists for `wingdings-book.ttf` (1), `wingdings2-book.ttf` (2) and `wingdings3-book.ttf` (3). The numbers on the left are the slot numbers. The names on the right are the names of the characters. FontForge can help to establish how your fonts differ from mine.

List 1:

```
33 pencil
34 scissors
35 scissorscutting
36 readingglasses
37 bell
38 book
39 candle
40 telephonesolid
41 telhandsetcirc
42 envelopeback
43 envelopefront
44 mailboxflagdwn
45 mailboxflagup
46 mailbxopnflgup
47 mailbxopnflgdwn
48 folder
49 folderopen
50 filetalltext1
51 filetalltext
52 filetalltext3
53 filecabinet
54 hourglass
55 keyboard
56 mouse2button
57 ballpoint
58 pc
59 harddisk
60 floppy3
61 floppy5
62 tapereel
63 handwrite
64 handwriteleft
65 handv
66 handok
67 thumbup
68 thumbdown
69 handptleft
70 handptright
71 handptup
72 handptdwn
73 handhalt
74 smileface
75 neutralface
76 frownface
77 bomb
78 skullcrossbones
79 flag
80 pennant
81 airplane
82 sunshine
83 droplet
84 snowflake
85 crossoutline
86 crossshadow
87 crossceltic
88 crossmaltese
89 starofdavid
90 crescentstar
91 yinyang
92 om
93 wheel
94 aries
95 taurus
96 gemini
97 cancer
98 leo
99 virgo
100 libra
101 scorpio
102 saggitarius
103 capricorn
104 aquarius
105 pisces
106 ampersanditlc
107 ampersandit
108 circle6
109 circleshadowdwn
110 square6
111 box3
112 box4
113 boxshadowdwn
114 boxshadowup
115 lozenge4
116 lozenge6
117 rhombus6
118 xrhombus
119 rhombus4
120 clear
121 escape
122 command
123 rosette
124 rosettesolid
125 quotedbllftbld
126 quotedblrtbld
128 zerosans
129 onesans
130 twosans
131 threesans
132 foursans
133 fivesans
134 sixsans
135 sevensans
136 eightsans
137 ninesans
138 tensans
139 zerosansinv
140 onesansinv
141 twosansinv
142 threesansinv
143 foursansinv
144 fivesansinv
145 sixsansinv
146 sevensansinv
147 eightsansinv
148 ninesansinv
149 tensansinv
150 budleafne
151 budleafnw
152 budleafsw
153 budleafse
154 vineleafboldne
155 vineleafboldnw
156 vineleafboldsw
157 vineleafboldse
158 circle2
159 circle4
160 square2
161 ring2
162 ring4
163 ring6
164 ringbutton2
165 target
166 circleshadowup
167 square4
168 box2
169 tristar2
170 crosstar2
171 pentastar2
172 hexstar2
173 octastar2
174 dodecastar3
175 octastar4
176 registersquare
177 registercircle
178 cuspopen
179 cuspopen1
180 query
181 circlestar
182 starshadow
183 oneoclock
184 twooclock
185 threeoclock
186 fouroclock
187 fiveoclock
188 sixoclock
189 sevenoclock
190 eightoclock
191 nineoclock
192 tenoclock
193 elevenoclock
194 twelveoclock
195 arrowdwnleft1
196 arrowdwnrt1
197 arrowupleft1
198 arrowuprt1
199 arrowleftup1
200 arrowrtup1
201 arrowleftdwn1
202 arrowrtdwn1
203 quiltsquare2
204 quiltsquare2inv
205 leafccwsw
206 leafccwnw
207 leafccwse
208 leafccwne
209 leafnw
210 leafsw
211 leafne
212 leafse
213 deleteleft
214 deleteright
215 head2left
216 head2right
217 head2up
218 head2down
219 circleleft
220 circleright
221 circleup
222 circledown
223 barb2left
224 barb2right
225 barb2up
226 barb2down
227 barb2nw
228 barb2ne
229 barb2sw
230 barb2se
231 barb4left
232 barb4right
233 barb4up
234 barb4down
235 barb4nw
236 barb4ne
237 barb4sw
238 barb4se
239 bleft
240 bright
241 bup
242 bdown
243 bleftright
244 bupdown
245 bnw
246 bne
247 bsw
248 bse
249 bdash1
250 bdash2
251 xmarkbld
252 checkbld
253 boxxmarkbld
254 boxcheckbld
255 windowslogo
```

List 2:

```
33 penballpoint
34 penfountain
35 brush
36 crayon
37 scissorsoutline
38 scissorschilds
39 telephone
40 telhandset
41 file1
42 file
43 file3
44 filetext1
45 filetext
46 filetext3
47 filetall1
48 filetall
49 filetall3
50 clipboard
51 trashcan
52 window
53 monitor
54 printer
55 fax
56 cd
57 tapecartridge
58 mouse1button
59 mouse3button
60 thumbbackup
61 thumbbackdwn
62 handptlft1
63 handptrt1
64 handptlftsld1
65 handptrtsld1
66 handbckptleft
67 handbckptright
68 handptlftsld
69 handptrtsld
70 handptup1
71 handptdwn1
72 handptupsld1
73 handptdwnsld1
74 handbckptup
75 handbckptdwn
76 handptupsld
77 handptdwnsld
78 handspreadback
79 xmark
80 check
81 boxxmark
82 boxcheck
83 boxx
84 boxxbld
85 circlex
86 circlexbld
87 prohibit
88 prohibitbld
89 ampersanditaldm
90 ampersandbld
91 ampersandsans
92 ampersandsandm
93 interrobang
94 interrobangdm
95 interrobangsans
96 interrobngsandm
97 budleafboldne
98 budleafboldnw
99 budleafboldsw
100 budleafboldse
101 vineleafne
102 vineleafnw
103 vineleafsw
104 vineleafse
105 zero
106 one
107 two
108 three
109 four
110 five
111 six
112 seven
113 eight
114 nine
115 ten
116 zeroinv
117 oneinv
118 twoinv
119 threeinv
120 fourinv
121 fiveinv
122 sixinv
123 seveninv
124 eightinv
125 nineinv
126 teninv
128 sun
129 moonfull
130 moonfirstqrtr
131 moonlastqrtr
132 capitulum
133 cross
134 crossbld
135 onethirty
136 twothirty
137 threethirty
138 fourthirty
139 fivethirty
140 sixthirty
141 seventhirty
142 eightthirty
143 ninethirty
144 tenthirty
145 eleventhirty
146 twelvethirty
147 quiltsquare
148 quiltsquareinv
149 circle1
150 circle3
151 circle5
152 circle7
153 ring1
154 ring3
155 ring5
156 ring7
157 ringbutton1
158 ringbutton3
159 square1
160 square3
161 square5
162 square7
163 box1
164 box5
165 box6
166 box7
167 boxbutton1
168 boxbutton2
169 boxbutton3
170 boxtarget
171 rhombus1
172 rhombus2
173 rhombus3
174 rhombus5
175 rhombopen
176 rhombbutton1
177 rhombbutton2
178 rhombbutton3
179 rhombtarget
180 lozenge1
181 lozenge2
182 lozenge3
183 lozenge5
184 lozengeopen
185 lozengebutton
186 semicircleleft
187 semicirclert
188 semicircleup
189 semicircledwn
190 squarecent
191 rhombuscent
192 pentagon1cent
193 pentagon2cent
194 hexagon1cent
195 hexagon2cent
196 octagon1
197 octagon2
198 cross1
199 cross2
200 cross3
201 cross4
202 cross5
203 cross6
204 cross7
205 x1
206 x2
207 x3
208 x4
209 x5
210 x6
211 x7
212 pentasterisk1
213 pentasterisk2
214 pentasterisk3
215 pentasterisk4
216 pentasterisk5
217 pentasterisk6
218 hexasterisk1
219 hexasterisk2
220 hexasterisk3
221 hexasterisk4
222 hexasterisk5
223 hexasterisk6
224 octasterisk1
225 octasterisk2
226 octasterisk3
227 octasterisk4
228 octasterisk5
229 tristar1
230 tristar3
231 crosstar1
232 crosstar3
233 pentastar1
234 pentastar3
235 hexstar1
236 hexstar3
237 octastar1
238 octastar3
239 dodecastar1
240 dodecastar2
241 tristar4
242 crosstar4
243 pentastar4
244 hexstar4
245 dodecastar4
246 cusp
247 cusp1
248 xdot
249 trihexasterisk
```

List 3:

```
33 a2left
34 a2right
35 a2up
36 a2down
37 a2nw
38 a2ne
39 a2sw
40 a2se
41 a2tableft
42 a2tabright
43 a2tabup
44 a2tabdown
45 a2home
46 a2end
47 a2pageup
48 a2pagedown
49 a2leftright
50 a2updown
51 a2leftdash
52 a2rightdash
53 a2updash
54 a2downdash
55 a2zigzag
56 a2cornerdwnleft
57 a2cornerdwnrt
58 a2cornerupleft
59 a2corneruprt
60 a2cornerleftup
61 a2cornerrightup
62 a2cornerleftdwn
63 a2cornerrtdwn
64 returnleft
65 returnright
66 newlineleft
67 newlineright
68 a2opleftrt
69 a2opdwnup
70 a2optableftrt
71 a2optabdwnup
72 a2parllleft
73 a2parllright
74 a2parllup
75 a2parlldown
76 a2uleftdown
77 a2urightup
78 a2ubelowright
79 a2uaboveleft
80 a2clockwise
81 a2cntrclockwise
82 escape1
83 enter
84 control
85 option
86 spacemark
87 nobreakspacemark
88 shiftlock
89 capslock
90 oleftshadow
91 orightshadow
92 oleftshadup
93 orightshadup
94 oleftshadlft
95 orightshadrt
96 oleftshadrt
97 orightshadlft
98 oleftoblqshad
99 orightoblqshad
100 oleftoblqshadup
101 orightoblqshadup
102 b2left
103 b2right
104 b2up
105 b2down
106 b2nw
107 b2ne
108 b2sw
109 b2se
110 b2leftright
111 b2updown
112 triangleup
113 triangledwn
114 triangleopenup
115 triangleopendwn
116 triangleleft
117 trianglert
118 triangleopenleft
119 triangleopenrt
120 triang45baseleft
121 triangle45basert
122 triangle45toppleft
123 triangle45toprt
124 triangle45left
125 triangle45right
126 triangle45up
128 triangle45down
129 trianglecentup
130 trianglecentdwn
131 trianglecentleft
132 trianglecentrt
133 headleft
134 headright
135 headup
136 headdown
137 c1left
138 c1right
139 c1up
140 c1down
141 c2left
142 c2right
143 c2up
144 c2down
145 c3left
146 c3right
147 c3up
148 c3down
149 c4left
150 c4right
151 c4up
152 c4down
153 a1left
154 a1right
155 a1up
156 a1down
157 a3left
158 a3right
159 a3up
160 a3down
161 a4left
162 a4right
163 a4up
164 a4down
165 d1left
166 d1right
167 e3left
168 e3right
169 f4left
170 f4right
171 g5left
172 g51
173 g5dash2
174 g5dash3
175 g5dash4
176 g5right
177 h6left
178 h6right
179 i8left
180 i8right
181 j6left
182 j6right
183 j6up
184 j6down
185 k6left
186 k6right
187 k6up
188 k6down
189 l7left
190 l7right
191 l7up
192 l7down
193 m9left
194 m9right
195 m9up
196 m9down
197 n7left
198 n7right
199 n7up
200 n7down
201 arrowdwnleft
202 arrowdwnrt
203 arrowupleft
204 arrowuprt
205 arrowleftup
206 arrowrtup
207 arrowleftdwn
208 arrowrtdwn
209 barb1left
210 barb1right
211 barb1up
212 barb1down
213 barb1nw
214 barb1ne
215 barb1sw
216 barb1se
217 barb3left
218 barb3right
219 barb3up
220 barb3down
221 barb3nw
222 barb3ne
223 barb3sw
224 barb3se
225 barb5left
226 barb5right
227 barb5up
228 barb5down
229 barb5nw
230 barb5ne
231 barb5sw
232 barb5se
233 drawleft
234 drawright
235 drawup
236 drawdown
237 drawdblleft
238 drawdblright
239 drawdblup
240 drawdbldown
```

I used `fontinst` to create the required support files. To do this, create the following files in a working directory which includes copies of the `.ttf` files.

`wingdings-drv.tex`:

```
\input fontinst.sty
\needsfontinstversion{1.926}
%:substitutions
%bold for bold extended
\substitutesilent{bx}{b}
\substitutesilent{b}{m}
%:record transformations for later map file creation
\recordtransforms{wingdings-rec.tex}
        \transformfont{wingdings-wingdings-book}{\reencodefont{wingdings}{\fromafm{wingdings-book}}}
        \transformfont{wingdings2-wingdings2-book}{\reencodefont{wingdings2}{\fromafm{wingdings2-book}}}
        \transformfont{wingdings3-wingdings3-book}{\reencodefont{wingdings3}{\fromafm{wingdings3-book}}}
        \installfonts
                \installfamily{U}{wingdings}{}
                \installfont{u-wingdings-book}{wingdings-wingdings-book}{txtfdmns,wingdings}{U}{wingdings}{m}{n}{}
                \installfontas{u-wingdings-book}{U}{wingdings}{m}{sc}{}
                \installfontas{u-wingdings-book}{U}{wingdings}{m}{it}{}
                \installfontas{u-wingdings-book}{U}{wingdings}{m}{sl}{}
                \installfamily{U}{wingdings2}{}
                \installfont{u-wingdings2-book}{wingdings2-wingdings2-book}{txtfdmns,wingdings2}{U}{wingdings2}{m}{n}{}
                \installfontas{u-wingdings2-book}{U}{wingdings2}{m}{sc}{}
                \installfontas{u-wingdings2-book}{U}{wingdings2}{m}{it}{}
                \installfontas{u-wingdings2-book}{U}{wingdings2}{m}{sl}{}
                \installfamily{U}{wingdings3}{}
                \installfont{u-wingdings3-book}{wingdings3-wingdings3-book}{txtfdmns,wingdings3}{U}{wingdings3}{m}{n}{}
                \installfontas{u-wingdings3-book}{U}{wingdings3}{m}{sc}{}
                \installfontas{u-wingdings3-book}{U}{wingdings3}{m}{it}{}
                \installfontas{u-wingdings3-book}{U}{wingdings3}{m}{sl}{}
        \endinstallfonts
\endrecordtransforms
\bye
```

`wingdings-map.tex`:

```
\input finstmsc.sty
\resetstr{PSfontsuffix}{.ttf}
\adddriver{dvips}{wingdings.map}
\input wingdings-rec.tex
\donedrivers
\bye
```

`wingdings.etx`:

```
\relax
\encoding
\nextslot{32}
\setslot{space}\endsetslot
\setslot{pencil}\endsetslot
\setslot{scissors}\endsetslot
\setslot{scissorscutting}\endsetslot
\setslot{readingglasses}\endsetslot
\setslot{bell}\endsetslot
\setslot{book}\endsetslot
\setslot{candle}\endsetslot
\setslot{telephonesolid}\endsetslot
\setslot{telhandsetcirc}\endsetslot
\setslot{envelopeback}\endsetslot
\setslot{envelopefront}\endsetslot
\setslot{mailboxflagdwn}\endsetslot
\setslot{mailboxflagup}\endsetslot
\setslot{mailbxopnflgup}\endsetslot
\setslot{mailbxopnflgdwn}\endsetslot
\setslot{folder}\endsetslot
\setslot{folderopen}\endsetslot
\setslot{filetalltext1}\endsetslot
\setslot{filetalltext}\endsetslot
\setslot{filetalltext3}\endsetslot
\setslot{filecabinet}\endsetslot
\setslot{hourglass}\endsetslot
\setslot{keyboard}\endsetslot
\setslot{mouse2button}\endsetslot
\setslot{ballpoint}\endsetslot
\setslot{pc}\endsetslot
\setslot{harddisk}\endsetslot
\setslot{floppy3}\endsetslot
\setslot{floppy5}\endsetslot
\setslot{tapereel}\endsetslot
\setslot{handwrite}\endsetslot
\setslot{handwriteleft}\endsetslot
\setslot{handv}\endsetslot
\setslot{handok}\endsetslot
\setslot{thumbup}\endsetslot
\setslot{thumbdown}\endsetslot
\setslot{handptleft}\endsetslot
\setslot{handptright}\endsetslot
\setslot{handptup}\endsetslot
\setslot{handptdwn}\endsetslot
\setslot{handhalt}\endsetslot
\setslot{smileface}\endsetslot
\setslot{neutralface}\endsetslot
\setslot{frownface}\endsetslot
\setslot{bomb}\endsetslot
\setslot{skullcrossbones}\endsetslot
\setslot{flag}\endsetslot
\setslot{pennant}\endsetslot
\setslot{airplane}\endsetslot
\setslot{sunshine}\endsetslot
\setslot{droplet}\endsetslot
\setslot{snowflake}\endsetslot
\setslot{crossoutline}\endsetslot
\setslot{crossshadow}\endsetslot
\setslot{crossceltic}\endsetslot
\setslot{crossmaltese}\endsetslot
\setslot{starofdavid}\endsetslot
\setslot{crescentstar}\endsetslot
\setslot{yinyang}\endsetslot
\setslot{om}\endsetslot
\setslot{wheel}\endsetslot
\setslot{aries}\endsetslot
\setslot{taurus}\endsetslot
\setslot{gemini}\endsetslot
\setslot{cancer}\endsetslot
\setslot{leo}\endsetslot
\setslot{virgo}\endsetslot
\setslot{libra}\endsetslot
\setslot{scorpio}\endsetslot
\setslot{saggitarius}\endsetslot
\setslot{capricorn}\endsetslot
\setslot{aquarius}\endsetslot
\setslot{pisces}\endsetslot
\setslot{ampersanditlc}\endsetslot
\setslot{ampersandit}\endsetslot
\setslot{circle6}\endsetslot
\setslot{circleshadowdwn}\endsetslot
\setslot{square6}\endsetslot
\setslot{box3}\endsetslot
\setslot{box4}\endsetslot
\setslot{boxshadowdwn}\endsetslot
\setslot{boxshadowup}\endsetslot
\setslot{lozenge4}\endsetslot
\setslot{lozenge6}\endsetslot
\setslot{rhombus6}\endsetslot
\setslot{xrhombus}\endsetslot
\setslot{rhombus4}\endsetslot
\setslot{clear}\endsetslot
\setslot{escape}\endsetslot
\setslot{command}\endsetslot
\setslot{rosette}\endsetslot
\setslot{rosettesolid}\endsetslot
\setslot{quotedbllftbld}\endsetslot
\setslot{quotedblrtbld}\endsetslot
\skipslots{1}
\setslot{zerosans}\endsetslot
\setslot{onesans}\endsetslot
\setslot{twosans}\endsetslot
\setslot{threesans}\endsetslot
\setslot{foursans}\endsetslot
\setslot{fivesans}\endsetslot
\setslot{sixsans}\endsetslot
\setslot{sevensans}\endsetslot
\setslot{eightsans}\endsetslot
\setslot{ninesans}\endsetslot
\setslot{tensans}\endsetslot
\setslot{zerosansinv}\endsetslot
\setslot{onesansinv}\endsetslot
\setslot{twosansinv}\endsetslot
\setslot{threesansinv}\endsetslot
\setslot{foursansinv}\endsetslot
\setslot{fivesansinv}\endsetslot
\setslot{sixsansinv}\endsetslot
\setslot{sevensansinv}\endsetslot
\setslot{eightsansinv}\endsetslot
\setslot{ninesansinv}\endsetslot
\setslot{tensansinv}\endsetslot
\setslot{budleafne}\endsetslot
\setslot{budleafnw}\endsetslot
\setslot{budleafsw}\endsetslot
\setslot{budleafse}\endsetslot
\setslot{vineleafboldne}\endsetslot
\setslot{vineleafboldnw}\endsetslot
\setslot{vineleafboldsw}\endsetslot
\setslot{vineleafboldse}\endsetslot
\setslot{circle2}\endsetslot
\setslot{circle4}\endsetslot
\setslot{square2}\endsetslot
\setslot{ring2}\endsetslot
\setslot{ring4}\endsetslot
\setslot{ring6}\endsetslot
\setslot{ringbutton2}\endsetslot
\setslot{target}\endsetslot
\setslot{circleshadowup}\endsetslot
\setslot{square4}\endsetslot
\setslot{box2}\endsetslot
\setslot{tristar2}\endsetslot
\setslot{crosstar2}\endsetslot
\setslot{pentastar2}\endsetslot
\setslot{hexstar2}\endsetslot
\setslot{octastar2}\endsetslot
\setslot{dodecastar3}\endsetslot
\setslot{octastar4}\endsetslot
\setslot{registersquare}\endsetslot
\setslot{registercircle}\endsetslot
\setslot{cuspopen}\endsetslot
\setslot{cuspopen1}\endsetslot
\setslot{query}\endsetslot
\setslot{circlestar}\endsetslot
\setslot{starshadow}\endsetslot
\setslot{oneoclock}\endsetslot
\setslot{twooclock}\endsetslot
\setslot{threeoclock}\endsetslot
\setslot{fouroclock}\endsetslot
\setslot{fiveoclock}\endsetslot
\setslot{sixoclock}\endsetslot
\setslot{sevenoclock}\endsetslot
\setslot{eightoclock}\endsetslot
\setslot{nineoclock}\endsetslot
\setslot{tenoclock}\endsetslot
\setslot{elevenoclock}\endsetslot
\setslot{twelveoclock}\endsetslot
\setslot{arrowdwnleft1}\endsetslot
\setslot{arrowdwnrt1}\endsetslot
\setslot{arrowupleft1}\endsetslot
\setslot{arrowuprt1}\endsetslot
\setslot{arrowleftup1}\endsetslot
\setslot{arrowrtup1}\endsetslot
\setslot{arrowleftdwn1}\endsetslot
\setslot{arrowrtdwn1}\endsetslot
\setslot{quiltsquare2}\endsetslot
\setslot{quiltsquare2inv}\endsetslot
\setslot{leafccwsw}\endsetslot
\setslot{leafccwnw}\endsetslot
\setslot{leafccwse}\endsetslot
\setslot{leafccwne}\endsetslot
\setslot{leafnw}\endsetslot
\setslot{leafsw}\endsetslot
\setslot{leafne}\endsetslot
\setslot{leafse}\endsetslot
\setslot{deleteleft}\endsetslot
\setslot{deleteright}\endsetslot
\setslot{head2left}\endsetslot
\setslot{head2right}\endsetslot
\setslot{head2up}\endsetslot
\setslot{head2down}\endsetslot
\setslot{circleleft}\endsetslot
\setslot{circleright}\endsetslot
\setslot{circleup}\endsetslot
\setslot{circledown}\endsetslot
\setslot{barb2left}\endsetslot
\setslot{barb2right}\endsetslot
\setslot{barb2up}\endsetslot
\setslot{barb2down}\endsetslot
\setslot{barb2nw}\endsetslot
\setslot{barb2ne}\endsetslot
\setslot{barb2sw}\endsetslot
\setslot{barb2se}\endsetslot
\setslot{barb4left}\endsetslot
\setslot{barb4right}\endsetslot
\setslot{barb4up}\endsetslot
\setslot{barb4down}\endsetslot
\setslot{barb4nw}\endsetslot
\setslot{barb4ne}\endsetslot
\setslot{barb4sw}\endsetslot
\setslot{barb4se}\endsetslot
\setslot{bleft}\endsetslot
\setslot{bright}\endsetslot
\setslot{bup}\endsetslot
\setslot{bdown}\endsetslot
\setslot{bleftright}\endsetslot
\setslot{bupdown}\endsetslot
\setslot{bnw}\endsetslot
\setslot{bne}\endsetslot
\setslot{bsw}\endsetslot
\setslot{bse}\endsetslot
\setslot{bdash1}\endsetslot
\setslot{bdash2}\endsetslot
\setslot{xmarkbld}\endsetslot
\setslot{checkbld}\endsetslot
\setslot{boxxmarkbld}\endsetslot
\setslot{boxcheckbld}\endsetslot
\setslot{windowslogo}\endsetslot
\endencoding
```

Continued in Part 2 ...

Answer (score 2):

Continues from Part 1 due to the character limit imposed on answers.

This is Part 2.

`wingdings2.etx`:

```
\relax
\encoding
\nextslot{32}
\setslot{space}\endsetslot
\setslot{penballpoint}\endsetslot
\setslot{penfountain}\endsetslot
\setslot{brush}\endsetslot
\setslot{crayon}\endsetslot
\setslot{scissorsoutline}\endsetslot
\setslot{scissorschilds}\endsetslot
\setslot{telephone}\endsetslot
\setslot{telhandset}\endsetslot
\setslot{file1}\endsetslot
\setslot{file}\endsetslot
\setslot{file3}\endsetslot
\setslot{filetext1}\endsetslot
\setslot{filetext}\endsetslot
\setslot{filetext3}\endsetslot
\setslot{filetall1}\endsetslot
\setslot{filetall}\endsetslot
\setslot{filetall3}\endsetslot
\setslot{clipboard}\endsetslot
\setslot{trashcan}\endsetslot
\setslot{window}\endsetslot
\setslot{monitor}\endsetslot
\setslot{printer}\endsetslot
\setslot{fax}\endsetslot
\setslot{cd}\endsetslot
\setslot{tapecartridge}\endsetslot
\setslot{mouse1button}\endsetslot
\setslot{mouse3button}\endsetslot
\setslot{thumbbackup}\endsetslot
\setslot{thumbbackdwn}\endsetslot
\setslot{handptlft1}\endsetslot
\setslot{handptrt1}\endsetslot
\setslot{handptlftsld1}\endsetslot
\setslot{handptrtsld1}\endsetslot
\setslot{handbckptleft}\endsetslot
\setslot{handbckptright}\endsetslot
\setslot{handptlftsld}\endsetslot
\setslot{handptrtsld}\endsetslot
\setslot{handptup1}\endsetslot
\setslot{handptdwn1}\endsetslot
\setslot{handptupsld1}\endsetslot
\setslot{handptdwnsld1}\endsetslot
\setslot{handbckptup}\endsetslot
\setslot{handbckptdwn}\endsetslot
\setslot{handptupsld}\endsetslot
\setslot{handptdwnsld}\endsetslot
\setslot{handspreadback}\endsetslot
\setslot{xmark}\endsetslot
\setslot{check}\endsetslot
\setslot{boxxmark}\endsetslot
\setslot{boxcheck}\endsetslot
\setslot{boxx}\endsetslot
\setslot{boxxbld}\endsetslot
\setslot{circlex}\endsetslot
\setslot{circlexbld}\endsetslot
\setslot{prohibit}\endsetslot
\setslot{prohibitbld}\endsetslot
\setslot{ampersanditaldm}\endsetslot
\setslot{ampersandbld}\endsetslot
\setslot{ampersandsans}\endsetslot
\setslot{ampersandsandm}\endsetslot
\setslot{interrobang}\endsetslot
\setslot{interrobangdm}\endsetslot
\setslot{interrobangsans}\endsetslot
\setslot{interrobngsandm}\endsetslot
\setslot{budleafboldne}\endsetslot
\setslot{budleafboldnw}\endsetslot
\setslot{budleafboldsw}\endsetslot
\setslot{budleafboldse}\endsetslot
\setslot{vineleafne}\endsetslot
\setslot{vineleafnw}\endsetslot
\setslot{vineleafsw}\endsetslot
\setslot{vineleafse}\endsetslot
\setslot{zero}\endsetslot
\setslot{one}\endsetslot
\setslot{two}\endsetslot
\setslot{three}\endsetslot
\setslot{four}\endsetslot
\setslot{five}\endsetslot
\setslot{six}\endsetslot
\setslot{seven}\endsetslot
\setslot{eight}\endsetslot
\setslot{nine}\endsetslot
\setslot{ten}\endsetslot
\setslot{zeroinv}\endsetslot
\setslot{oneinv}\endsetslot
\setslot{twoinv}\endsetslot
\setslot{threeinv}\endsetslot
\setslot{fourinv}\endsetslot
\setslot{fiveinv}\endsetslot
\setslot{sixinv}\endsetslot
\setslot{seveninv}\endsetslot
\setslot{eightinv}\endsetslot
\setslot{nineinv}\endsetslot
\setslot{teninv}\endsetslot
\skipslots{1}
\setslot{sun}\endsetslot
\setslot{moonfull}\endsetslot
\setslot{moonfirstqrtr}\endsetslot
\setslot{moonlastqrtr}\endsetslot
\setslot{capitulum}\endsetslot
\setslot{cross}\endsetslot
\setslot{crossbld}\endsetslot
\setslot{onethirty}\endsetslot
\setslot{twothirty}\endsetslot
\setslot{threethirty}\endsetslot
\setslot{fourthirty}\endsetslot
\setslot{fivethirty}\endsetslot
\setslot{sixthirty}\endsetslot
\setslot{seventhirty}\endsetslot
\setslot{eightthirty}\endsetslot
\setslot{ninethirty}\endsetslot
\setslot{tenthirty}\endsetslot
\setslot{eleventhirty}\endsetslot
\setslot{twelvethirty}\endsetslot
\setslot{quiltsquare}\endsetslot
\setslot{quiltsquareinv}\endsetslot
\setslot{circle1}\endsetslot
\setslot{circle3}\endsetslot
\setslot{circle5}\endsetslot
\setslot{circle7}\endsetslot
\setslot{ring1}\endsetslot
\setslot{ring3}\endsetslot
\setslot{ring5}\endsetslot
\setslot{ring7}\endsetslot
\setslot{ringbutton1}\endsetslot
\setslot{ringbutton3}\endsetslot
\setslot{square1}\endsetslot
\setslot{square3}\endsetslot
\setslot{square5}\endsetslot
\setslot{square7}\endsetslot
\setslot{box1}\endsetslot
\setslot{box5}\endsetslot
\setslot{box6}\endsetslot
\setslot{box7}\endsetslot
\setslot{boxbutton1}\endsetslot
\setslot{boxbutton2}\endsetslot
\setslot{boxbutton3}\endsetslot
\setslot{boxtarget}\endsetslot
\setslot{rhombus1}\endsetslot
\setslot{rhombus2}\endsetslot
\setslot{rhombus3}\endsetslot
\setslot{rhombus5}\endsetslot
\setslot{rhombopen}\endsetslot
\setslot{rhombbutton1}\endsetslot
\setslot{rhombbutton2}\endsetslot
\setslot{rhombbutton3}\endsetslot
\setslot{rhombtarget}\endsetslot
\setslot{lozenge1}\endsetslot
\setslot{lozenge2}\endsetslot
\setslot{lozenge3}\endsetslot
\setslot{lozenge5}\endsetslot
\setslot{lozengeopen}\endsetslot
\setslot{lozengebutton}\endsetslot
\setslot{semicircleleft}\endsetslot
\setslot{semicirclert}\endsetslot
\setslot{semicircleup}\endsetslot
\setslot{semicircledwn}\endsetslot
\setslot{squarecent}\endsetslot
\setslot{rhombuscent}\endsetslot
\setslot{pentagon1cent}\endsetslot
\setslot{pentagon2cent}\endsetslot
\setslot{hexagon1cent}\endsetslot
\setslot{hexagon2cent}\endsetslot
\setslot{octagon1}\endsetslot
\setslot{octagon2}\endsetslot
\setslot{cross1}\endsetslot
\setslot{cross2}\endsetslot
\setslot{cross3}\endsetslot
\setslot{cross4}\endsetslot
\setslot{cross5}\endsetslot
\setslot{cross6}\endsetslot
\setslot{cross7}\endsetslot
\setslot{x1}\endsetslot
\setslot{x2}\endsetslot
\setslot{x3}\endsetslot
\setslot{x4}\endsetslot
\setslot{x5}\endsetslot
\setslot{x6}\endsetslot
\setslot{x7}\endsetslot
\setslot{pentasterisk1}\endsetslot
\setslot{pentasterisk2}\endsetslot
\setslot{pentasterisk3}\endsetslot
\setslot{pentasterisk4}\endsetslot
\setslot{pentasterisk5}\endsetslot
\setslot{pentasterisk6}\endsetslot
\setslot{hexasterisk1}\endsetslot
\setslot{hexasterisk2}\endsetslot
\setslot{hexasterisk3}\endsetslot
\setslot{hexasterisk4}\endsetslot
\setslot{hexasterisk5}\endsetslot
\setslot{hexasterisk6}\endsetslot
\setslot{octasterisk1}\endsetslot
\setslot{octasterisk2}\endsetslot
\setslot{octasterisk3}\endsetslot
\setslot{octasterisk4}\endsetslot
\setslot{octasterisk5}\endsetslot
\setslot{tristar1}\endsetslot
\setslot{tristar3}\endsetslot
\setslot{crosstar1}\endsetslot
\setslot{crosstar3}\endsetslot
\setslot{pentastar1}\endsetslot
\setslot{pentastar3}\endsetslot
\setslot{hexstar1}\endsetslot
\setslot{hexstar3}\endsetslot
\setslot{octastar1}\endsetslot
\setslot{octastar3}\endsetslot
\setslot{dodecastar1}\endsetslot
\setslot{dodecastar2}\endsetslot
\setslot{tristar4}\endsetslot
\setslot{crosstar4}\endsetslot
\setslot{pentastar4}\endsetslot
\setslot{hexstar4}\endsetslot
\setslot{dodecastar4}\endsetslot
\setslot{cusp}\endsetslot
\setslot{cusp1}\endsetslot
\setslot{xdot}\endsetslot
\setslot{trihexasterisk}\endsetslot
\endencoding
```

`wingdings3.etx`:

```
\relax
\encoding
\nextslot{32}
\setslot{space}\endsetslot
\setslot{a2left}\endsetslot
\setslot{a2right}\endsetslot
\setslot{a2up}\endsetslot
\setslot{a2down}\endsetslot
\setslot{a2nw}\endsetslot
\setslot{a2ne}\endsetslot
\setslot{a2sw}\endsetslot
\setslot{a2se}\endsetslot
\setslot{a2tableft}\endsetslot
\setslot{a2tabright}\endsetslot
\setslot{a2tabup}\endsetslot
\setslot{a2tabdown}\endsetslot
\setslot{a2home}\endsetslot
\setslot{a2end}\endsetslot
\setslot{a2pageup}\endsetslot
\setslot{a2pagedown}\endsetslot
\setslot{a2leftright}\endsetslot
\setslot{a2updown}\endsetslot
\setslot{a2leftdash}\endsetslot
\setslot{a2rightdash}\endsetslot
\setslot{a2updash}\endsetslot
\setslot{a2downdash}\endsetslot
\setslot{a2zigzag}\endsetslot
\setslot{a2cornerdwnleft}\endsetslot
\setslot{a2cornerdwnrt}\endsetslot
\setslot{a2cornerupleft}\endsetslot
\setslot{a2corneruprt}\endsetslot
\setslot{a2cornerleftup}\endsetslot
\setslot{a2cornerrightup}\endsetslot
\setslot{a2cornerleftdwn}\endsetslot
\setslot{a2cornerrtdwn}\endsetslot
\setslot{returnleft}\endsetslot
\setslot{returnright}\endsetslot
\setslot{newlineleft}\endsetslot
\setslot{newlineright}\endsetslot
\setslot{a2opleftrt}\endsetslot
\setslot{a2opdwnup}\endsetslot
\setslot{a2optableftrt}\endsetslot
\setslot{a2optabdwnup}\endsetslot
\setslot{a2parllleft}\endsetslot
\setslot{a2parllright}\endsetslot
\setslot{a2parllup}\endsetslot
\setslot{a2parlldown}\endsetslot
\setslot{a2uleftdown}\endsetslot
\setslot{a2urightup}\endsetslot
\setslot{a2ubelowright}\endsetslot
\setslot{a2uaboveleft}\endsetslot
\setslot{a2clockwise}\endsetslot
\setslot{a2cntrclockwise}\endsetslot
\setslot{escape1}\endsetslot
\setslot{enter}\endsetslot
\setslot{control}\endsetslot
\setslot{option}\endsetslot
\setslot{spacemark}\endsetslot
\setslot{nobreakspacemark}\endsetslot
\setslot{shiftlock}\endsetslot
\setslot{capslock}\endsetslot
\setslot{oleftshadow}\endsetslot
\setslot{orightshadow}\endsetslot
\setslot{oleftshadup}\endsetslot
\setslot{orightshadup}\endsetslot
\setslot{oleftshadlft}\endsetslot
\setslot{orightshadrt}\endsetslot
\setslot{oleftshadrt}\endsetslot
\setslot{orightshadlft}\endsetslot
\setslot{oleftoblqshad}\endsetslot
\setslot{orightoblqshad}\endsetslot
\setslot{oleftoblqshadup}\endsetslot
\setslot{orightoblqshadup}\endsetslot
\setslot{b2left}\endsetslot
\setslot{b2right}\endsetslot
\setslot{b2up}\endsetslot
\setslot{b2down}\endsetslot
\setslot{b2nw}\endsetslot
\setslot{b2ne}\endsetslot
\setslot{b2sw}\endsetslot
\setslot{b2se}\endsetslot
\setslot{b2leftright}\endsetslot
\setslot{b2updown}\endsetslot
\setslot{triangleup}\endsetslot
\setslot{triangledwn}\endsetslot
\setslot{triangleopenup}\endsetslot
\setslot{triangleopendwn}\endsetslot
\setslot{triangleleft}\endsetslot
\setslot{trianglert}\endsetslot
\setslot{triangleopenleft}\endsetslot
\setslot{triangleopenrt}\endsetslot
\setslot{triang45baseleft}\endsetslot
\setslot{triangle45basert}\endsetslot
\setslot{triangle45toppleft}\endsetslot
\setslot{triangle45toprt}\endsetslot
\setslot{triangle45left}\endsetslot
\setslot{triangle45right}\endsetslot
\setslot{triangle45up}\endsetslot
\skipslots{1}
\setslot{triangle45down}\endsetslot
\setslot{trianglecentup}\endsetslot
\setslot{trianglecentdwn}\endsetslot
\setslot{trianglecentleft}\endsetslot
\setslot{trianglecentrt}\endsetslot
\setslot{headleft}\endsetslot
\setslot{headright}\endsetslot
\setslot{headup}\endsetslot
\setslot{headdown}\endsetslot
\setslot{c1left}\endsetslot
\setslot{c1right}\endsetslot
\setslot{c1up}\endsetslot
\setslot{c1down}\endsetslot
\setslot{c2left}\endsetslot
\setslot{c2right}\endsetslot
\setslot{c2up}\endsetslot
\setslot{c2down}\endsetslot
\setslot{c3left}\endsetslot
\setslot{c3right}\endsetslot
\setslot{c3up}\endsetslot
\setslot{c3down}\endsetslot
\setslot{c4left}\endsetslot
\setslot{c4right}\endsetslot
\setslot{c4up}\endsetslot
\setslot{c4down}\endsetslot
\setslot{a1left}\endsetslot
\setslot{a1right}\endsetslot
\setslot{a1up}\endsetslot
\setslot{a1down}\endsetslot
\setslot{a3left}\endsetslot
\setslot{a3right}\endsetslot
\setslot{a3up}\endsetslot
\setslot{a3down}\endsetslot
\setslot{a4left}\endsetslot
\setslot{a4right}\endsetslot
\setslot{a4up}\endsetslot
\setslot{a4down}\endsetslot
\setslot{d1left}\endsetslot
\setslot{d1right}\endsetslot
\setslot{e3left}\endsetslot
\setslot{e3right}\endsetslot
\setslot{f4left}\endsetslot
\setslot{f4right}\endsetslot
\setslot{g5left}\endsetslot
\setslot{g51}\endsetslot
\setslot{g5dash2}\endsetslot
\setslot{g5dash3}\endsetslot
\setslot{g5dash4}\endsetslot
\setslot{g5right}\endsetslot
\setslot{h6left}\endsetslot
\setslot{h6right}\endsetslot
\setslot{i8left}\endsetslot
\setslot{i8right}\endsetslot
\setslot{j6left}\endsetslot
\setslot{j6right}\endsetslot
\setslot{j6up}\endsetslot
\setslot{j6down}\endsetslot
\setslot{k6left}\endsetslot
\setslot{k6right}\endsetslot
\setslot{k6up}\endsetslot
\setslot{k6down}\endsetslot
\setslot{l7left}\endsetslot
\setslot{l7right}\endsetslot
\setslot{l7up}\endsetslot
\setslot{l7down}\endsetslot
\setslot{m9left}\endsetslot
\setslot{m9right}\endsetslot
\setslot{m9up}\endsetslot
\setslot{m9down}\endsetslot
\setslot{n7left}\endsetslot
\setslot{n7right}\endsetslot
\setslot{n7up}\endsetslot
\setslot{n7down}\endsetslot
\setslot{arrowdwnleft}\endsetslot
\setslot{arrowdwnrt}\endsetslot
\setslot{arrowupleft}\endsetslot
\setslot{arrowuprt}\endsetslot
\setslot{arrowleftup}\endsetslot
\setslot{arrowrtup}\endsetslot
\setslot{arrowleftdwn}\endsetslot
\setslot{arrowrtdwn}\endsetslot
\setslot{barb1left}\endsetslot
\setslot{barb1right}\endsetslot
\setslot{barb1up}\endsetslot
\setslot{barb1down}\endsetslot
\setslot{barb1nw}\endsetslot
\setslot{barb1ne}\endsetslot
\setslot{barb1sw}\endsetslot
\setslot{barb1se}\endsetslot
\setslot{barb3left}\endsetslot
\setslot{barb3right}\endsetslot
\setslot{barb3up}\endsetslot
\setslot{barb3down}\endsetslot
\setslot{barb3nw}\endsetslot
\setslot{barb3ne}\endsetslot
\setslot{barb3sw}\endsetslot
\setslot{barb3se}\endsetslot
\setslot{barb5left}\endsetslot
\setslot{barb5right}\endsetslot
\setslot{barb5up}\endsetslot
\setslot{barb5down}\endsetslot
\setslot{barb5nw}\endsetslot
\setslot{barb5ne}\endsetslot
\setslot{barb5sw}\endsetslot
\setslot{barb5se}\endsetslot
\setslot{drawleft}\endsetslot
\setslot{drawright}\endsetslot
\setslot{drawup}\endsetslot
\setslot{drawdown}\endsetslot
\setslot{drawdblleft}\endsetslot
\setslot{drawdblright}\endsetslot
\setslot{drawdblup}\endsetslot
\setslot{drawdbldown}\endsetslot
\endencoding
```

For each `.ttf`, you need to create an `.afm`. There are different ways to do this. `ttf2afm` is one option and is included in TeX Live. The following assumes a Unix-ish system, but you can alternatively create the AFM files using FontForge or any similar tool of your choice.

```bash
ttf2afm wingdings-book.ttf > wingdings-book.afm
ttf2afm wingdings2-book.ttf > wingdings2-book.afm
ttf2afm wingdings3-book.ttf > wingdings3-book.afm
```

Now you can run

```bash
tex wingding-drv.tex
```

This will create a number of files. You need now to convert the `.pl` files to TFMs and the `.vpl` files to VFs. On a Unix-type system, you can loop over the files using something like

```bash
for i in *.pl
do
  pltotf $i
done
for i in *.vpl
do
  vptovf $i
done
```

You also need to run

```bash
tex wingding-map.tex
```

to produce the `.map` file fragment etc.

Finally, create a simple `.sty` for convenient use with LaTeX.

`wingding.sty`:

```latex
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{wingding}[2007/12/22 v1.0 wingding CFR]
\RequirePackage{pifont}
\pdfmapfile{+wingdings.map}
\Pifont{wingdings}
\Pifont{wingdings2}
\Pifont{wingdings3}

\gdef\wingding#1#2{%
        \def\tempa{#1}%
        \def\tempb{1}%
        \def\tempc{2}%
        \def\tempd{3}%
        \ifx\tempa\tempb
                \Pisymbol{wingdings}{#2}%
        \fi
        \ifx\tempa\tempc
                \Pisymbol{wingdings2}{#2}%
        \fi
        \ifx\tempa\tempd
                \Pisymbol{wingdings3}{#2}%
        \fi}

\endinput
%% end wingding.sty
```

I recommend installing the files into TEXMFLOCAL. You can find out where this is using

```bash
kpsewhich -var TEXMFLOCAL
```

Create the following sub-directories within this local tree.

At the top-level, make 3 directories with cascading sub-directories:

```bash
doc/fonts/wingding/  
fonts/  
tex/latex/wingding/
```

For example, if TEXMFLOCAL is `/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/`, you might use

```bash
mkdir -p /usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/doc/fonts/wingding
mkdir -p /usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/fonts
mkdir -p /usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/tex/latex/wingding
```

Within the top-level `fonts` directory, you need a number of directories with sub-directories:

```bash
afm/microsoft/wingding/  
enc/dvips/cfr/
map/pdftex/wingding/  
tfm/microsoft/wingding/  
truetype/microsoft/wingding/  
vf/microsoft/wingding/
```

[Obviously you don't need to use `cfr` here - substitute your user name or whatever you prefer.]

Now move files into directories as follows.

`doc/fonts/wingding`:

```bash
wingdings-drv.tex  
wingdings-map.tex  
wingdings.etx  
wingdings2.etx  
wingdings3.etx
```

`fonts/afm/microsoft/wingding`:

```bash
wingdings-book.afm  
wingdings2-book.afm  
wingdings3-book.afm
```

`fonts/enc/dvips/cfr`:

```bash
wingdings.enc  
wingdings2.enc  
wingdings3.enc
```

`fonts/map/pdftex/wingding`:

```bash
wingdings.map
```

`fonts/tfm/microsoft/wingding`:

```bash
u-wingdings-book.tfm   
u-wingdings3-book.tfm  
wingdings-wingdings-book.tfm  
wingdings2-wingdings2-book.tfm  
wingdings3-wingdings3-book.tfm   
u-wingdings2-book.tfm  
wingdings-book.tfm     
wingdings2-book.tfm           
wingdings3-book.tfm
```

`fonts/truetype/microsoft/wingding`:

```bash
wingdings-book.ttf  
wingdings2-book.ttf  
wingdings3-book.ttf
```

`fonts/vf/microsoft/wingding`:

```bash
u-wingdings-book.vf  
u-wingdings2-book.vf  
u-wingdings3-book.vf
```

`tex/latex/wingding`:

```bash
uwingdings.fd  
uwingdings2.fd  
uwingdings3.fd  
wingding.sty
```

Now run

```bash
mktexlsr $(kpsewhich -var TEXMFLOCAL)
```

and the font(s) should be reading to use.

```latex
\usepackage{wingding}
```

(You do NOT need to run `updmap-sys` using this method as the configuration is only suitable for use with pdfTeX and so the `.map` file fragment is added on-the-fly by the package `wingding`.)

For example,

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{wingding}
\begin{document}
  \wingding1{150}\wingding1{151}\wingding1{152}\wingding1{153}

  \wingding1{154}\wingding1{155}\wingding1{156}\wingding1{157}

  \wingding2{33}\wingding2{34}\wingding3{100}\wingding3{105}
\end{document}
```

produces

[image: Wingdings 1, 2 & 3]